# database design for online bus ticket booking with extra features

Tags: ticket-system

I am trying to build online bus ticket reservation system on a package base, where the ticket includes other features like ticket of some site seeing places, bus ticket will be same for all passenger but price for other features may depends on passenger type(Adult/Child/Senior ...). There will be a tables like other_feature,passenger_type,feature_type, so i am confused how to relate these with reservation system please any help be appreciated . Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2):

My table Structure

**table  reservation_details**

id
passenger_id
travel_detail_id
purchase_detail_id
reserved_date
seat_no
depature_date

**table travel_details**

id
bus_id
route_id
depature_time
arrival_time
fare
freq_detail_id

**table routes**

id
name
distance
from_city
to_city

**table freq_details**

id
sun
mon
tue
wed
thu
fri
sat